# Django: Admin with multiple sites & languages

Tags: python, django, multilingual, sites, multiple-sites

I'm supposed to build some Django apps, that allow you to administer multiple sites through one backend. The `contrib.sites` framework is quite perfect for my purposes. I can run multiple instances of `manage.py` with different settings for each site; but how should django's admin deal with different settings for different sites, eg. if they have different sets of languages, a different (default) language? So there are some problem s to face if you have to work on objects coming from different sites in one admin...

I think `settings.ADMIN_FOR` is supposed to be quite helpful for cases like this, but theres hardly any documentation about it and I think it's not really used in the actual Django version (?).

So any ideas/solutions are welcome and much appreciated!
Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old [blog post by James Bennet](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/03/django-tips-scaling-application/) which might be helpful:

> 1. Create a new Site object in your admin for each domain, and put the id of that Site into its settings file as SITE_ID so Django knows which site in the database corresponds to this settings file.
> 2. In the settings file for your original site (the one with id 1), add the other sites’ settings files to the ADMIN_FOR setting, to let Django know that this one instance of the admin application will handle all of the sites.

As documented ADMIN_FOR (for which i can not post link) should be a tuple of settings modules much like INSTALED_APPS is a tuple of django app modules.

Note that blog post is from 2006 so it uses a bit outdated API.

Comment: Well that's exactly the information I have got. I'd be interested in HOW and WHERE Django would handle this issues in the Admin, so I did a search for "ADMIN_FOR" in Django's source code, and I couldnt find a place where it's really used, except once for displaying debugging informations...

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to be used only for admindocs and template validator. Strange. And the only topic on google seems to be yours. Have you tried on django-users, perhaps some of the core devs knows more.

Comment: I posted it on django-users as well, if anybody wants to join: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/d48353ba7fb1c741